# How to operate a dataframe based on lat, lon, time in R?

Tags: r, where-clause, polygon, r-raster

I am new to R, come from a background of working with raster and netCDF files, and I tried looking for an answer to this question, but could not find anything.

There is this dataframe which has time and spatial variables. Time is represented by `Year` and the spatial location can be both related to the `ADM2_PCODE` or with the polygon built by lat,lon pairs in the column `geometry`. I would like to find a way to select each location with at least 5 years of data (`Valor != NA`). I imagine this could be indexed either via the `ADM2_PCODE` or `geometry`.

In a normal netcdf operation, I would use something like `where(sum(Valor != NA).dim('Year')>= 5)`. However, here the situation requires to use either a table or vector solution, and I have no experience with operating vectors. I am aware it is possible to convert the table to raster at a specific resolution, but I believe it is best to minimize errors and residuals by keeping the operation either in table format or vector. I wonder if anyone could help me with this.

Tiny example of how the dataframe/table looks like:

```
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -62.8941 ymin: -13.1178 xmax: -61.88647 ymax: -11.82782
CRS:           NA
   Year ADM2_PCODE Valor                       geometry
1 1981    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
2 1982    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
3 1983    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
4 1984    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
5 1985    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
6 1986    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for such a solution. I added some more data:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
  group_by(ADM2_PCODE) %>% 
  count(duration_year = max(Year)-min(Year) & !is.na(Valor))
```

dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1981, 
1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986), ADM2_PCODE = c(1100015, 1100015, 
1100015, 1100015, 1100015, 1100015, 1100016, 1100016, 1100016, 
1100016, 1100016, 1100016), Valor = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), geometry = c("MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", 
"MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", 
"MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", 
"MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...", 
"MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...", 
"MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...", 
"MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Output:

```
  ADM2_PCODE duration_year     n
       <dbl> <lgl>         <int>
1    1100015 FALSE             6
2    1100016 TRUE              6
```

Comment: Hi TarJae, thank you for the reply. The answer is quite good, the only thing I would ask you is if it is possible to select only the cases with numbers (duration_year == TRUE perhaps?)? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Just add `filter(duration_year == TRUE)`. Like: `df %>%  
    group_by(ADM2_PCODE) %>% 
    count(duration_year = max(Year)-min(Year) & !is.na(Valor)) %>% 
    filter(duration_year == TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very interesting how different the pipeline concept of R is from numpy/pandas. My very last point is that I want to have a mask defining `n >= 5` as true and `n < 5`, so I thought of using something like: `df_duration$time_mask <- ifelse(df_duration$n > 5, TRUE, FALSE)`. However, is there a way of doing this still within the pipeline? Thank you!

Comment: You could `mutate` a new column and use `ifelse` statement. Like so: `df %>%  
    group_by(ADM2_PCODE) %>% 
    count(duration_year = max(Year)-min(Year) & !is.na(Valor)) %>% 
    filter(duration_year == TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(time_mask = ifelse(n > 5, TRUE, FALSE))`